# How to use UpdatePanel in content page when ScriptManager is in MasterPage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, master-pages

I'm facing a problem that doesn't seems to have a solution.

I have a MasterPage with a `ScriptManager` as you can see right below:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" >
    <Scripts><asp:ScriptReference Path="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" /></Scripts>
    <Scripts><asp:ScriptReference Path="js/jquery-ui.min.js" /></Scripts>
    <Scripts><asp:ScriptReference Path="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js" /></Scripts>
    <Scripts><asp:ScriptReference Path="js/bootstrap.js" /></Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

And, in one of my Content Pages i have an `UpdatePanel`:

```
<div id="cad_cpf" class="cad_cpf">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCpf" CssClass="lblCpf" Text="* CPF:" Width="200px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCpf" CssClass="txtCpf" MaxLength="14" CausesValidation="True" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtCpf_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpTeste" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional" style="display:inline-block;">
         <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlMensagemCpf" Visible="false"><asp:Label runat="server" Text="CPF já cadastrado. " CssClass="validacao" ID="lblMensagemCpf"></asp:Label><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hplLogar" CssClass="validacao linkLogar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Login">Fazer login!</asp:HyperLink></asp:Panel>
         </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCpf" CssClass="validacao" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCpf" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Campo obrigatório" ValidationGroup="pessoa_fisica" EnableClientScript="False" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regCPF" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCPF" CssClass="validacao" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="Digite o CPF corretamente" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d{2}$" ValidationGroup="pessoa_fisica"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</div>
```

All i want to do is to refresh the `UpdatePanel` so it can shows a Panel (with a Label and a Hyperlink) in the TextChanged event of a TextBox.

It seems like a have tried everything, but nothing works!

I tried to put the TextBox inside the ContentTemplate changing ChildrenAsTriggers to "true", but it didn't work.

I tried to use the `Update()` method in code behind, but it didn't work.

The funny fact is that if i set the TextBox as a `PostBackTrigger` it works perfectly (except for the fact that it refreshes the entire page), but when I set the TextBox as `AsyncPostBackTrigger` it does nothing.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: If you place a breakpoint on ` txtCpf_TextChanged` does it get hit?

Comment: You have `ChildrenAsTriggers` as false, and you don't have that control registered as an AsyncPostbackTrigger. Please show the version of your code that corrects one of those, probably registering it.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but it still didn't work.

I tried to put the UpdatePanel on MasterPage and the ContentTemplate inside it and it works... but now the UpdatePanel is not working on second postback. Can somebody help me?